# If $\langle x, y \rangle = 0$, why is $\langle x - \mu_x \boldsymbol{1}, y - \mu_y \boldsymbol{1} \rangle = 0$ intuitively?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

If $\langle \boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y} \rangle = 0$, where $\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y}$ are vectors, then $\langle \boldsymbol{x} - \mu_\boldsymbol{x} \boldsymbol{1}, \boldsymbol{y} - \mu_\boldsymbol{y} \boldsymbol{1} \rangle = 0$? $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$ are the means of the vector $x$ and $y$.

I proved this below
$$
\langle \boldsymbol{x} - \mu_\boldsymbol{x} \boldsymbol{1}, \boldsymbol{y} - \mu_\boldsymbol{y} \boldsymbol{1} \rangle \\
= \langle \boldsymbol{x} , \boldsymbol{y}  \rangle - \langle \mu_x \boldsymbol{1} , \boldsymbol{y}  \rangle
- \langle \mu_y \boldsymbol{1} , \boldsymbol{x} \rangle  + \langle \mu_y \boldsymbol{1}, \mu_x \boldsymbol{1} \rangle \\
= 0 - \langle \mu_x \boldsymbol{1} , \boldsymbol{y}  \rangle
- \langle \mu_y \boldsymbol{1} , \boldsymbol{x} \rangle  + \mu_x \mu_y \langle  \boldsymbol{1}, \boldsymbol{1} \rangle \\
\langle \mu_y \boldsymbol{1} , \boldsymbol{x} \rangle = \left( \frac{\sum_i y_i}{N} \right) (\sum_i x_i) \\
\langle \mu_x \boldsymbol{1} , \boldsymbol{y} \rangle = \left( \frac{\sum_i x_i}{N} \right) \sum_i y_i \\
\mu_x \mu_y \langle  \boldsymbol{1}, \boldsymbol{1} \rangle = 2N \left( \frac{\sum_i y_i}{N} \right) \left( \frac{\sum_i x_i}{N} \right)
$$
So we can conclude the expression evaluates to zero. But I am having trouble making sense of this intuitively. Is there an intuitive explanation for why this holds?

Comment: This isn't true--the factor of $2$ in your final equation shouldn't be there.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh you're right. This makes more sense to me now that I couldn't interpret this.